# Set size of height with width on display:none element children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problems understanding what is happening in my code and hope some of you might shed some light on it.

So Im using jQuery slideUp and slideDown functions to reveal and hide my nav menu for small screens:

```
function init_menu(){
    $( "#menu-button" ).click(function () {
        if ( $( "#filter-box-nav" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
            $( "#filter-box-nav" ).slideDown( "fast" );
        } else {
            $( "#filter-box-nav" ).slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
}
```

And the styling for the elements targeted are:

```
#filter-box-nav {
    width: 99%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F4FA5C;
    display: none;
}
.filter-box {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: .5%;
    width: 17.5%;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

I use the function:

```
function style_nav_elements() {
    $(".filter-box").css("height", $(".filter-box:first").width());
}
```

to resize the elements at the end of a javascript window.onload. But the pixel size of the elements are set to the set CSS percentage 17.5%. But when the menu is opened and the resize event handler is triggered and executes the function to change the elements hight it works perfectly. What is happening in my code and what am i doing wrong?

Additionally, if there is any recommendations to how this is usually solved I appreciate pointers and advice.

HTML:

```
<nav id="filter-box-nav">
    <ul id="filter-box-container">
        <li id="work" class="filter-box"></li>
        <li id="education" class="filter-box"></li>
        <li id="webdevelopment" class="filter-box"></li>
        <li id="art" class="filter-box"></li>
        <li id="comics" class="filter-box"></li>
        <li id="design" class="filter-box"></li>
        <li id="miscellaneous" class="filter-box"></li>
        <li id="personal" class="filter-box"></li>
        <!-- <li id="Uncategorized" class="filter-box"></li> -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: im not sure i understand the issue. Can you explain it a different way?

Comment: Ill try!
Why does the jQuery css() set the height of my element to the percentage of the width when the parent element is set to: display:hidden? But when the parent element is visible by the jQuery slideDown() function it uses the pixel width of the element and not the percentage.